# php code for displaying the products with no description in magento

Tags: php, magento

How to display the products which do not have description or short description in magento.

PHP code would be more than sufficient for this problem..
Please help me out.....

Doing manually would be "naive", also takes lot of time to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to show products on list page without   description or short description  or you want to get just list of those products ?

for getting list you can use the below code

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('description', array('neq' => 'NULL' ))
->addFieldToFilter('short_description', array('neq' => 'NULL' ))    ;
foreach($collection  as $collection1 ) {
        echo  $collection1->getId()."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: I wanna show that on a html page.... I tried out your code.. But it seems not working.. Is there any other characters stored in the db instead of null?

Comment: what the output you get when you run the above code ?

Comment: It will print the collection array...!

Comment: I did not get anything... I used it inside a controller and called it externally..

Comment: please use my updated code, that is tested and working fine.